# Very slow StreamReader for medium sized files.

Tags: c#, optimization, character-encoding, streamreader

I am reading text files into program(they are code in Unicode, the output must be in utf-8). The code below works fine for smaller ones (around 150 lines, where line is one word only), however when I am using it on bigger files(like 20.000 line, still only one word on which line) the program takes areound half a minute to complete its task. Should I write new code, or is there a way to optimize this?

```
int next;
string storage = "";
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path))
        { 
            while( (next = sr.Read()) != -1 )
            {
                storage += Char.ConvertFromUtf32(next);
            }
            sr.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Yes: StreamReader.ReadToEnd(). See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readtoend(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I went with new sr(path, Encoding.Unicode) and then I received more than just int which improved complexity by 99999999. Thanks guys for answers, Please close this thread.

Comment: Use Filehelpers.net http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use StringBuilder instead of String:

```
int next;
StringBuilder storage = new StringBuilder();
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path)) {
    while ((next = sr.Read()) != -1) {
        storage.Append(Char.ConvertFromUtf32(next));
    }
    sr.Close();
}
string result = storage.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

So, everything start working really smoothly when I used different StreamReader, 
`using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path, Encoding.Unicode))`
this, let me get properly formated string, not int indicating character, this has improved speed by A LOT.